# Windos store unit test project stopped compiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

Suddenly I started to get a compile error:

> 'vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.exe' which is not part of the payload

**Nothing** has changed.

Tried to create a completely new VS Solution and added a new Unit test lib for Windows store app. Same error.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The "quickest" solution seemed to be a repair of Visual Studio.